# Null pointer assignment error

Tags: c

This is a simple C program for linklist, and its showing some runtime error!
"Null Pointer Assignment"

Never heard of it and I don't see any errors in the code?

What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}node;

void main()
{
node *head,*P;
int n,i;

printf("Enter no. of elements\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Enter %d data elements\n",n);
head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
scanf("%d",&(head->data));
head->next = NULL;
P=head;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
P->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
P=P->next;
P->next=NULL;
scanf("%d",P->data);
}

while(P!=NULL)
{
printf("%d",P=P->data);
P=P->next;
}

}
```

Comment: Please indent you code, to have us read it.

Comment: Yaa its working now! actually I encountered it for the first time.. so got a bit confused! thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many errors here:

- `malloc` is called without a prototype in scope. (To fix, `#include <stdlib.h>`).
- The return value of `malloc` is not checked
- `scanf("%d",P->data);` should be `scanf("%d",&P->data);`
- `printf("%d",P=P->data);` should be `printf("%d",P->data);`

You should have gotten warnings about most of these. Don't ignore your compiler output messages.

Any of those could have caused your error (although I'd guess `P=P->data` as the most likely).

Also, reset `P = head;` before trying to print out your list, otherwise you're starting at the end and so you won't get any output.

Comment: Thnks! the last one really helped! was getting just a single element!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.faqs.org/qa/qa-3786.html

**NULL pointer Assignment**

> A NULL pointer assignment is a runtime error It occurs due to various
>   reasons one is that ur program has tried to access an illegal memory
>   location.    Illegal location means either the location is in the
>   operating systems address space or in the other processes memory
>   space.   In stdio.h NULL is defined as 0   So whenever your program
>   tries to access 0th location the operating system kills your program
>   with runtime assignment error because  the 0th location is in the
>   operating systems address space and operating system doesnt allow
>   access to its address space  by user program

**Example code:**

```
int* ptr = NULL;  
*ptr = 8;
```

**Explanation:**

On almost every system, address 0 is reserved. System won't allow you to write to that location. If you try, you will get a runtime exception

Some Changes in your code!

- Include `#include<stdlib.h>` library for malloc.
- Change `scanf("%d",P->data);` to `scanf("%d",&P->data);`
- And `printf("%d",P=P->data);` to `printf("%d",P->data);`
- Write `P=head` reset head before printing!

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/uR3zAs).

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors in program:

`scanf("%d",P->data);` --> `scanf("%d",&P->data);`

`printf("data %d \n", P=P->data);` --> `printf("data %d \n", P->data);`

And when you are running the `while` loop your pointer `P` is pointing to last node therefore crash is happening. Do  `P=head` just before the `while`  loop.